# Postgresql Connection with Database in Java fail

Tags: java, android, jdbc, postgis, postgresql-9.2

I try to connect from my Android app to my postgresql server running on Windows 7. Both is running on my computer with a special IP. I try

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://xx.xx.xx.xx:5432/postgis20";
connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"postgres","xxxx");
```

The app is running in a simulator on my pc. Connect contains after the procedure null and Exceiption I get is **The connection attempt failed.** So what I do wrong with the connection?
If I try to connect via the SQL Shell everything is working fine and I use the same parameter. SSL is set to no.

I also tried to use instead of my ip localhost or 127.0.0.1 but that has the same result.

I changed the permission settings to allow the access to the internet.
But now I get the following error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occured to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use jdbc on Android it is necessary to use the StrictMode. That can be done by using the following code lines:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: Hi , where do I place this code , in connection class or  MainActivity ?